# In which order does sCons execute builders?

Tags: python, build, scons

I wrote four SCons builders for precompile, compile, assembler and linker. I mean to use the precompiler output for post compile script, while the other three builders should build the actual executable.

If I leave out the precompiler, everything works well.

If I add the precompiler, SCons calls the precompiler and then the linker. Of course there are no object files and the link process breaks.
Furthermore the output of the preprocessor is put in the path specified for the compiler output, so SCons ignores the output path given by VariantDir().

I Tried to add the builder in different orders, but it does not seem to help. Any ideas?

```
------------- Preparser -------------------------
builders['preParser'] = Builder(action=Action(preParserCommand),
                                suffix=".i",
                                src_suffix=".c",
                                single_source=1)
currentOutputPath = "C:\\Users\\BLABLUB\\Desktop\\TMP"
tool['preParser'].VariantDir(currentOutputPath, os.path.relpath(ps.sourcePath), duplicate=0)
tool['preParser']["BUILDERS"] = {"run": builders['preParser']}
tool['preParser']["PLATFORM"] = currentTool["arch"]
tool['preParser']["PRINT_CMD_LINE_FUNC"] = print_cmd_line
tool['preParser'].Decider("MD5-timestamp")


------------- Compiler --------------------------
builders[key] = Builder(action=Action(currentCommands[key]["command"]),
                                suffix=currentCommands[key]   ["suffix_target"],
                                src_suffix=currentCommands[key]["suffix_source"],
                                single_source=1)
        tool[key].VariantDir(os.path.relpath(
            outputPaths[key]), os.path.relpath(ps.sourcePath), duplicate=0)
        tool[key]["BUILDERS"] = {"run": builders[key]}
        tool[key]["PLATFORM"] = currentTool["arch"]
        tool[key]["PRINT_CMD_LINE_FUNC"] = print_cmd_line
        tool[key].Decider("MD5-timestamp")
        continue

------------- Assembler ---------------------------------
...

# compile
targets += tool["compiler"].run(compFileList)

# precompile
targets += tool['preParser'].run(compFileList)

# disassemble
targets += tool["assembler"].run(assemFileList)

# link
finalTargetSuffix = currentCommands["linker"]["suffix_target"]
fTarget = tool["linker"].run(finalTarget + finalTargetSuffix, targets)
```

Comment: Can you add a full simple SConstruct which demonstrates your issue? It's hard to help you without more info.